# Implementing F using a demultiplexer and an extra AND gate

Tags: design, multiplexer, logic-gates

Use a   1-to-8  Demultiplexer   and an  extra   AND gate    to  create  the function:

F(x,y,z)    =   ∑m(1,3,5)

If I were using an OR gate I think this would be trivial, simply put the 1 3 and 5 from the demultiplexer in to an OR gate and have the output go to F. But using an AND gate for this, I have no idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output F needs to be active for all odd numbers *except* 7. So...

LSB to mux 2<sup>0</sup> input, mux outputs '0' for even numbers and '1' for odd numbers. AND gate detects 7, output to mux 2<sup>1</sup> input forces it to output '3' instead of '1'.

[image]